# Hive: how to eliminate the duplicated substrings

Tags: hive, duplicates, hiveql

Hive table:

```
  create table T (i int, s string);

  insert into T values
  (1, "a1&b2"),
  (1, "b2&c3"),
  (2, "c1&d2"),
  (2, "c1");
```

The s column contains the values separated by &

Desired output should group by 1st column and concatenate the s column but have only one unique substring values (separated by &):

```
   i    grouped_s
   --   -------------
   1    a1&b2&c3
   2    c1&d2
```

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT i,
concat_ws('&',
 collect_set(
  split(concat_ws('&' , collect_set(s)), "&" )
 )
)
as grouped_s
FROM T group by i;
```

I got this:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 6:24 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'collect_set'
```

Also I would like to make it without using the nested SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lateral view + explode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView):

```
select t.i, concat_ws('&',collect_set(e.val)) as grouped_s
  from T t 
       lateral view outer explode(split(t.s,'&')) e as val
 group by t.i;
```

Result:

```
t.i grouped_s
1   a1&b2&c3
2   c1&d2
```